# WKWebView lost body in NSURLProtocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, nsurlprotocol

When I use NSURLProtocol to catch the requests from WKWebView, the body is lost. Any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

NSURLRequest objects never have body data in protocols.  You have to instead get the body stream, open it, and read the data in a streaming fashion.

For best performance, you should also resend that data to the write end of a new bound stream pair and provide the read end as the body stream in the new request.  (Use the CFStreamCreateBoundPair function in the Core Foundation API and use a bridged cast it to cast the CFStreamRef object to an NSStream object.)

Comment: Where should I do this ? NSURLProtocol delegate method ? Which one please

Comment: Several methods.  Minimally: store a reference to the stream in `initWithRequest:cachedResponse:client:`, create the stream pair and assign a custom stream delegate class instance to provide the data for it in `startLoading`, and stop any in-progress loading in stopLoading.

Comment: Wait a sec.  I just reread the question.  WKWebView is out-of-process, and doesn't support NSURLProtocol at all, so you won't get any call there, with a body or not.  Was this question supposed to be about UIWebView?  *confused*

Comment: NO, this question only about WKWebview, UIWebView works perfectly